# Замена символов в массиве?

Tags: php

Массив:

```
array('text//qwe//val',
    array(
        'text//qwe//va2',
        'text//qwe//va3',
        array(
            'text//qwe//va4',
            'text//qwe//va5',
        )
));
```

Как мне вырезать с массива text//qwe и потом все // заменить на \\ ?
Массив может быть с вложеностью больше 15.

Comment: `foreach`, рекурсия и `str_replease`

Comment: Я не знаю рекурсии, вот и спрашую тут.

Comment: 2 подзаголовок http://www.php.su/functions/custom/?3

Comment: зачем это вам ?

Comment: А что если взять это текстом а не кодом, одна регулярка с заменой и результат на исполнение :)